# Flux2 Image Reflector Controller not able to find a match on my image tags

Tags: fluxcd

I'm working with Flux2. I'm new to Flux and I'm trying to set up the Image Reflector controller to find the last image tag in my image registry but I'm getting an error on my image policy 'unable to determine latest version from provided list'

In my registry I have the following tags:

```
    16
    rc-9.20.7975.18473
```

Flux is reporting that it's connecting to my image registry and says 'successful scan, found 2 tags'.  Based on my image policy below I was expecting only 1 tag to match.

Here is my Image Policy:

```
apiVersion: image.toolkit.fluxcd.io/v1beta1
kind: ImagePolicy
metadata:
  name: xxxxxxxx
spec:
  imageRepositoryRef:
    name: xxxxxxxx
  filterTags:
    pattern: '^rc-(?P<ts>.*)'
    extract: '$ts'
  policy:
    semver:
      range: '^9.20.x.x'
```

I would like to it update on new 'rc' images. Any thoughts on why the Image Reflector is saying it found 2 tags when '16' isn't a match by the filter pattern?  What should I change in my Image Policy to determine the latest version?  Thx!

Answer (score 0):

Your range is not correct. It should be '>=9.20.0.0'. For more details check https://fluxcd.io/flux/components/image/imagepolicies/